# Font OT1/ptm/m/n/9=ptmr7t at 9.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

Tags: fonts, installing, texmaker, ubuntu

My `.tex` file failed the LaTeX compile with one of this problem, my OS is Ubuntu 12.04, and it seems to have the same problem in Fedora 16. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: How dit you load the fonts? ptm is Adobe Times which is not shipped in any of the TeX installations. What is shipped is utm which is URW++ variant of Times. Normally `updmap.cfg` contains a setting which fonts should be used. Best is, show a minimal document!

Comment: dnf install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended.noarch in fedora

Comment: I can't post an answer as the question is closed but installing the `times`  font fixed it for me: `tlmgr install times`.

Answer (score 26):

Install texlive-fonts-recommended:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-recommended
```

Comment: Just chucking on a comment because this never got accepted - this solved the problem for me completely.

Comment: I don't know if this should be closed as too localized, and not accepted. This can be refined into a proper question and a solution that is helpful. It is the 1st google result for "Font OT1 not loadable". And the answer does help.

Comment: I agree with nebffa and luk32. This answer met my needs perfectly.

Comment: how about in Fedora? is there an equivalent package?

Comment: @orm, Looking here: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/TeXLive, I would imagine the package you're looking for is texlive-collection-fontsextra or maybe texlive-collection-fontsrecommended.

Comment: `tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended` is a way through the latex package manager